# Redirection plugin did not working

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins

i have wordpress website.
i used plugin to redirect url, but plugin did not respond properly.
i tried 3 diff plugins.
what should i do for that?
for reference here i put my url

old url: http://www.firsttraffic.com.au/#!traffic-management/ccfn

new url: http://www.firsttraffic.com.au/our-services/traffic-management/

i want to redirect old to new url

Comment: okey.. thanks  no issues i'll try

Answer (score 0):

It's may cause for wordpress version or server behavior or other reasons.

Test [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) too.

and for visitors you can say google to transfer them for more info [click here](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/how-to-change-domain-names-keep-your-rankings-in-google/).

Comment: thanks. i have tried but still its not working. this plugin also give me result 0hits and null result of last access

Comment: i tried.. redirection, seo redirection quick redirection and 301-redirection. but none of them working

Comment: It's my cause for server restrictions contact them